# Concat function SQL with variable different number of values

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following issue:

```
Declare @var nvarchar(100)
SET @var = 'ID,Name'

Declare @var2 nvarchar(100) 
SET @var2='ID'

select concat(@var) FROM Test
select concat(@var2) FROM Tes
```

I have a select statement where I have a variable with the column to get from a table. This Query is in dynamic sql in reality but with the example above you get whta it is about.
I have to concat variable and then convert it. But my problem is that I don't know if therae is one value in the variable or several. I got error when I try to concat the variable with one value. How can I check in the select statement if there is more than one value so I know that I can concat it?

Comment: if there are multiple values will they always be separated by a `,`?

Comment: The number of "values" is: `Len( @Var ) - Len( Replace( @Var, ',', '' ) ) + 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh, you have defined a constant string, not a list of columns.  If you want a list of columns, then you need to use `exec`, preferably with `sp_executesql`:

```
Declare @var nvarchar(100);
set @var = 'ID,Name';

declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = 'select concat(@cols) from test';

set @sql = replace(@sql, '@cols', @var);

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Note:  Because `concat()` requires at least two arguments, you can include an empty string if you want this to work on only one column:

```
Declare @var nvarchar(100);
set @var = 'ID,Name';

declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = 'select concat('''', @cols) from test';

set @sql = replace(@sql, '@cols', @var);

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: But this isn.t my problem. The problem is how to check the number of cols?

Comment: Good idea with empty string, can i don an LTRIM to delete it then?

Comment: @Mcol . . . You don't need to check the number of columns if you use an empty string.